# Pushing to multidimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a for loop like this:

```
var mappedPoints = new Array();    

for (i=0; i<livePoints.length; i++){
            var xOptions = [];
            var useX;
            var useY;
            for (j=0; j<madeMapPoints.length; j++){
                if(parseFloat(livePoints[i].Latitude) < parseFloat(madeMapPoints[i].xpoint)){
                    break;
                }
                xOptions.push(madeMapPoints[i]);
                useX = parseFloat(madeMapPoints[i].xpoint);
            }

            for(k=0;k<xOptions.length;k++){
                if(parseFloat(livePoints[i].Longitude) < parseFloat(xOptions[k].ypoint)){
                    break;
                }
                useY = parseFloat(xOptions[k].ypoint);
            }
            var num = Math.pow(parseInt(useX+useY),2);
            mappedPoints[num].push(livePoints[i]);
        }
```

Around the bottom there's the line that says `mappedPoints[num].push(livePoints[i]);`. What I want to have happen is push to the index I'm defining in num so if the same value comes up in NUM again, it will be pushed to the array key defined in num.

What I have doesn't work. The PHP equivalent do what I want would be something like this:

```
$mappedPoints[$useX."_".$useY][] = livePoints[i];
```

Could I accomplish the same result with JS somehow?

Comment: So why do you use `$useX."_".$useY` key in your PHP version and completely different `Math.pow(parseInt(useX+useY),2)` key in your JavaScript version?

Comment: I'm using the parseInt one because it returns an int. PHP version returns a string.

Comment: Well, I mean that they are completely different by expected result. In one case it might be something like 1.234_5.678, in another case it might be something like 9. It is easy to mimic what you mentioned as PHP version in JavaScript if it is something you are really looking for. It would be (useX + "_" + useY).

Comment: @skovalyov I'm not sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: It is not 100% clear what you want to achieve and how exactly it fails. Add `trace(num);` above `mappedPoints[num].push()` and check the console - this will give a better insight. Otherwise extend your code extract with some real life input data and put it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

You should check if `mappedPoints[num]` is an array first.
But I think in this case what you need for `mappedPoints` is not an array, you need an object.

In javascript, associative arrays don't exist, but they can be simulated with an object.
It's a bit confusing, because both can be accessed the same way.

At the beggining:

```
var mappedPoints = {}; //this way you define mappedPoints to be an object
```

At the end:

```
if(!mappedPoints.hasOwnProperty(num))
    mappedPoints[num] = []; //this way you define mappedPoints[num] to be an array

mappedPoints[num].push(livePoints[i]);
```